# i can't get/show the value of an input into a span(in an IFRAME)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

**I want to put/show the value from input into the frame's span, live. Below I have the code..**
**This is main html page called 'i1.html'**

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="input">
    <iframe src="i2.html" frameborder="1" id="myfrm" width="300px" height="1000px"></iframe>
    <script>
        const frame = document.getElementById("myfrm");
        const elmnt = frame.contentWindow.document.getElementById("my-message");
        const inp = document.getElementById("input");
        const inp2 = document.getElementById("input2");
        
        addEvent(inp, 'keyup', function () {
            elmnt.value = this.value.split(' ').join('');
        });
        function addEvent(ele, evnt, funct) {
            if (ele.addEventListener) // W3C    
                return ele.addEventListener(evnt, funct, false);
            else if (ele.attachEvent)  // IE    
                return ele.attachEvent("on" + evnt, funct);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

**and this is the frame called 'i2.html'**

```
<body>
    <p>
        <strong>Message:</strong>
        <span id="my-message"></span>
    </p>

</body>
```

**And it shows me this error: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null***